# Formatting div height in grid

Tags: css, html, grid

I have this  [link to my jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/dankellaway/UtWVJ/1/)

I am trying to format the columns of the grid to have the same height on both sides and other grids to line up correctly underneath. In this example the half column has more info (the heights are different). I want the other half to have the same height. Is this achievable?

Thanks, the code is as follows:

```
 <style>
 #page {
    width:95%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
#row {
    height:100%
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 143, 213);
    height:50px;
}
#full {
    width:99%;
    margin:0.5%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#half {
    width:48%;
    margin:0.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 50%;
}
#third {
    width:32.333%;
    float:left;
    margin:0.5%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#quarter {
    width:23%;
    margin:0.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    height:200px
}
</style>

<div id="page">
<div id="full">FULL</div>
<div id="half">
    <h1>Half</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec. Curabitur posuere enim eget turpis feugiat tempor. Etiam ullamcorper lorem dapibus velit suscipit ultrices. Proin in est sed erat facilisis pharetra.</div>
<div id="half">
    <h1>Half</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sodales urna non odio egestas tempor. Nunc vel vehicula ante. Etiam bibendum iaculis libero, eget molestie nisl pharetra in. In semper consequat est, eu porta velit mollis nec. Curabitur posuere enim eget turpis feugiat tempor.</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
<div id="quarter">Quarter</div>
<div id="quarter">Quarter</div>
<div id="quarter">Quarter</div>
<div id="quarter">Quarter</div>
<div id="row">
    <div id="half">Half
        <br>test</div>
    <div id="quarter">Quarter</div>
    <div id="quarter">Quarter</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this would affect your intended styling overall, but assigning a fixed pixel height to your `#half` divs rather than a percentage will force them to be the same height.

```
#half {
    width:48%;
    margin:0.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 300px;
}
```

***Update***

I dug a little deeper and found that

> "The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the root element is
>   relative to the initial containing block." [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)

So basically, you have 2 options. 
1) As I originally suggested, assign a fixed pixel height rather than a percentage.
2) Assign a fixed pixel height to the `#page` div. Your `#half` divs can now use percentages, which will measue based off of the `#page` div. For example:

```
#page {
    width:95%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    height:1000px
}
#half {
    width:48%;
    margin:0.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Will result in your `#half` divs being <strike>~500px (not including `margin` and `padding`)</strike> 505px. The extra 5 pixels being the 0.5% `padding` that is also calculated from the `#page` height.